# TASM error: CS unreachable from current segment

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, tasm

I recently installed tasm for winxp using windows xp mode and installed it. The tasm and tlink commands work, but I get an error at either MAIN PROC or START:, same error for both.

This is my code to input a number and output that same number:

```
.model small    
.stack 100h
.code
.data

start:
mov ah,1
int 21h

mov dl,al
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

end start
```

and the error I get is:

```
name.asm(5) CS unreachable from current segment
```

Is it possible this is due to my software? Initially I was using tasm w/DOSBox for win7, but that kept resetting on it's own and showing symbols all over the screen.
  [image]

Comment: Maybe you intended to put `.data` before `.code` (they seem to be backwards)?

Comment: so it would be `.model small` `.stack` `.data` `.code` `start:`

Answer (score 0):

The OP's code started with the following. I've added comments:

```
.model small    ; Code and Data max 64K
.stack 100h     ; Only 256 bytes of stack
.code           ; Start writing code...
.data           ; Start giving some data...

start:          ; Here's the entry point
mov ah,1        ; Put 1 into ah
```

And the assembler was giving the error `CS unreachable from the current segment`.

@Michael Petch pointed out that by opening the `.data` segment and then writing code, the OP was trying to put code into the data segment - which the assembler didn't like. By swapping the `.code` and `.data` statements, the assembler was satisfied.